# UITableView crashes when it scrolls to non-top side and saying index 2 beyond bounds [0..1]

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, crash, indexing

Now I meet a strange situation, I need your help, and forgive my poor English.

When a UITableView, filled with NSArray, on the top, really reload data when I  use `[UITableView reloadData]`. But, the table doesn't reload data if it's not on the top side. In fact, the app crashed. The strange thing is that the `indexPath.section` isn't the right value, bigger than real value. So the console said: `index 2 beyond bounds [0..1]`.

Does anybody know why? Please give me a hand or a tips.

Below are some codes:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (pageCount == 0) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IPOCalendarTableTitle" object:nil];
        return 0;
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *arrayMonths = [stockArray objectAtIndex:pageIndex];
        NSMutableArray *arrayDays = [arrayMonths objectAtIndex:0];
        IPOListing *listing = [arrayDays objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy/MM/dd";
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:listing.date];
        NSString *s = nil;

        NSArray *arrayMonthEN = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Jan", @"Feb", @"Mar", @"Apr", @"May", @"Jun", @"Jul", @"Aug", @"Sep", @"Oct", @"Nov", @"Dec", nil];
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if ([delegate.currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"SC"]) {
            formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy年M月";
            s = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        } else if ([delegate.currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"TC"]) {
            formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy年M月";
            s = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        } else if ([delegate.currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"EN"]) {
            int year = [[listing.date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] intValue];
            int month = [[listing.date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 2)] intValue];
            s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %d", [arrayMonthEN objectAtIndex:month - 1], year];
        }

        [formatter release];

        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:s, [NSNumber numberWithInt:pageCount], [NSNumber numberWithInt:pageIndex], nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IPOCalendarTableTitle" object:array];
        NSLog(@"%d", [arrayMonths count]);
        return [arrayMonths count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSMutableArray *arrayMonths = [stockArray objectAtIndex:pageIndex];
    NSMutableArray *arrayDays = [arrayMonths objectAtIndex:section];
    return [arrayDays count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 36.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"IPOCalendarCellIdentifier";
    IPOCalendarCell *cell = (IPOCalendarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IPOCalendarCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.lineLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSLog(@"%d, %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);

    NSMutableArray *arrayMonths = [self.stockArray objectAtIndex:pageIndex];
    NSMutableArray *arrayDays = [arrayMonths objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    IPOListing *listing = [arrayDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // configuration the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that 1. creates the data, 2. returns the number of sections (`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`).

Comment: In which line exactly is it crashing?

Comment: In numberOfSectionsInTableView, returns 2, in numberOfRowsInSection, returns 1 and 0. but in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I print the indexPath.section and indexPath.row, there are 2 and 1!! Really strange ----So index 2 beyond bounds [0..1].

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: which line does the debugger highlight when it crashes?

Comment: Sorry, it crashes at the statement 'NSMutableArray *arrayDays = [arrayMonths objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];' in method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

If indexPath.section isn't the right value, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the value you return in - (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInSection:(UITableView *)tableView

Check this first, because If the size of your array is two, so as the value return by numberOfRowsInSection:, indexPath.section can't be equal or greater than this value.

Comment: In numberOfSectionsInTableView, returns 2, in numberOfRowsInSection, returns 1 and 0. but in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I print the indexPath.section and indexPath.row, there are 2 and 1!! Really strange.

Comment: It is, but it certainly don't come from iOS :) Check if our mutable arrays are not changing each time you call numberOfSectionsInTableView (like adding a new element in it)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The problem is not here, it is about that two gang tables. When I use [UITableView setContentOffset] to table A, B will refresh too. In this case table A will reloadData twice, and when contentOffset of table is zero, it will reloadData only once. When table reloadData twice in quick time, it crashes. Thank all of you and I feel so sorry for my mistake.